# Unable to switch keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, input-source

I just rebooted and for some reason am unable to switch keyboard layouts.  This feature had been working previously since just after getting the computer (and setting up the alternate keyboard layout).

The secondary input source is shown here:

[image]

My attempt to select the alternate input source is shown here:  note I clicked on `usd2`.  However **the input source did not change as a result**.

[image]

I did not do anything related to keyboard settings for quite some time so it is puzzling this problem just showed up.  I am on Sierra with MBPro 2015.

Comment: Do you have Siri turned on?  If so, turn it off and change its keyboard shortcut to "none" and restart and see if that helps.

Comment: You are using a custom keyboard layout.  Do you have the same problem when using one provided with MacOS, like Spanish or French or ABC Extended?

Comment: Instead of clicking on the input menu in the menu bar, can you change the keyboard via the standard keyboard shortcut Control plus Space (or sometimes Command plus Space)?

Comment: @TomGewecke Siri has always been off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-added the *same* keyboard input:

[image]

.. and the *second* one is working.

[image]

I have no idea why this *suddenly* started failing.

Comment: Do you have two of them also showing in system preferences/keyboard/input sources?

Comment: @TomGewecke updated the answer